# mule process csv file with same set of data

Tags: mule

In mule I have a CSV file containing 50 rows of records like product id, product name, quantity, price, offer, expire date. I want to convert the CSV format to a JSON  format and I use an external API using the above data. While in mid calling, the API network goes down. How can I retry with same data.
Can anybody shed light on this

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create an exception catcher that would log the failure requests, then run through those again.

Do not keep "looping" the same record until the API comes up. This will block all others from being processed and your queue will not decrease.

See [this post](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/when-etl-met-the-esb-introducing-the-batch-module/) which explains how to setup batch jobs and [this post](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/handle-errors-batch-job/) on how to create error handlers; both from the mulesoft blog.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `until-successful` router: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

NOTE: This is by default asynchronous, but can be configured to be synchronous.